# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: oracle, firefox, ssl, mozilla, oracle11g

I've googled this error but came up with no solution, this happened when I installed oracle database 11g, I tried to reach https://localhost:1158/em and this error pops up in firefox

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:1158.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

    *   The page you are trying to view can not be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

    *   Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this broken site.
```

Anyone had similar problem before, I'd be thrilled if someone could help. thank you

Comment: It may be that the port isn't using SSL. Try using http://localhost:1158/em instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the dbconsole was secured and is actually an SSL service? Try to connect to http://localhost:1158/em and see what happens...

Comment: I just did that .. tnx I tried it before reading here but thanx for the thought